# Javascript to cycle through divs and show different content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create some javascript for my web page that is able to change divs and the content that's inside on a mouse click.
I'm using `display: none;` and `display: block;` to determine which div is shown.

```
function CycleDivsWithClick(div1, div2, div3, div4) {
  d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
  d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
  d3 = document.getElementById(div3);
  d4 = document.getElementById(div4);

  if (d1.style.display == "block") {
    d1.style.display = "none";
    d2.style.display = "block";
    d3.style.display = "none";
    d4.style.display = "none";
  } else if (d2.style.display == "block") {
    d1.style.display = "none";
    d2.style.display = "none";
    d3.style.display = "block";
    d4.style.display = "none";
  } else if (d3.style.display == "block") {
    d1.style.display = "none";
    d2.style.display = "none";
    d3.style.display = "none";
    d4.style.display = "block";
  } else if (d4.style.display == "block") {
    d1.style.display = "block";
    d2.style.display = "none";
    d3.style.display = "none";
    d4.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    d1.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

I can only get this code to work if I add the final else statement shown above.  Even then the script has to be clicked once before it will work as expected.  Why does it do this?  Even though my div1 (alpha) is initially set to `display: block;`  from the css.

[Example code in CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMKpLv)

My full code actually displays background images.  My hope is to get it to pre-download all images so it won't load the image upon the mouse click.

I'd also prefer to avoid jQuery for now as I'd like to learn the basics before progressing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `element.style` returns the properties set through the style attribute (*which is not set initially but is instead done through the CSS rules*).

You could use the `window.getComputedStyle` method

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/WrQMvw?editors=001

Comment: Thanks it works now.  Thanks for the explanation.  I was a bit confused at first because I thought the style tag was exactly what css was, but provides it inline.  Then I tried removing display settings from my css and moved it inline under the style tag and my original code worked. [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyyLNN)

Comment: @smally you are correct the style tag is the same but just inline. The issue was with the way you were accessing the properties. The `getComputedStyle` is the way to read the actual applied style. The `element.style` points to the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

for your extra else statement in jquery code you can change your html code belong alpha div like this

```
<div id="bravo" style="display:block;">
    Some text within Bravo
  </div>
```

[Sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwyePB)